# NetSuite Advanced PDF Creation via Button

Tags: netsuite

I've created a button on an estimate form to print an advanced PDF.
However, I get the below error in the log

> java.lang.java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

I've read somewhere it might have to do with images in the template, but I have tried taking them out and still get the error.
Does anyone have any idea for me about this?

The code to generate/render the PDF is:

```
* @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 * @NModuleScope Public
 */
define([
    'SuiteScripts/Directory/Library.js'
,   'N/render'
,   'N/record'
],
function (Library, render, record)
{
    /**
     * Main entry function
     *
     * @param {Object} context
     * @returns {Void}
     */
    function PrintPriceIncreaseQuote(context)
    {
        var renderer = null;

        try
        {
            if (context.request.method == 'GET')
            {
                renderer = createRenderer(context);
                printTemplate(context.response, renderer);
            }
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            Library.errorHandler('PrintPriceIncreaseQuote', e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create renderer
     *
     * @param {Object} context
     * @returns {Object} renderer
     */
    function createRenderer(context)
    {
        var renderer = null;
        var recordId = 0;

        try
        {
            recordId = context.request.parameters.id;

            //Create the renderer object
            renderer = render.create();
            renderer.setTemplateByScriptId('CUSTTMPL_125_4099_SB7_165');
            renderer.addRecord({templateName: 'record',
                record: record.load({
                    type: record.Type.ESTIMATE,
                    id: recordId
                })
            });
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            Library.errorHandler('createRenderer', e);
        }
        return renderer;
    }

    /**
     * Print merged template
     *
     * @param {Object} response
     * @param {Object} renderer
     * @returns {Void}
     */
    function printTemplate(response, renderer)
    {
        var pdfFile = null;

        try
        {
            pdfFile = renderer.renderAsPdf();
            response.writeFile({file: pdfFile, isInline: true});
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            Library.errorHandler('printTemplate', e);
        }
    }

    return {
        onRequest: PrintPriceIncreaseQuote
    };
});
'''/**
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, it works well with my XML/PDF templates. Check the XML DOM structure.

Comment: Thanks fullstack studio, it appears it is the images in my template. If i take out all references to them, it works. However, I need the images in the pdf output.

Comment: Also, this is the part in the XML/PDF template that I believe is causing the issue    <td align="right"><#if companyInformation.logoUrl?length != 0><img src="${subsidiary.logo@url}" width="105.48" height="60.84"/></#if></td> is there something i can add in the script for it to handle images?

Comment: I put the company logo into Documents(you can create a folder for images or use existing one). <img height="19" src="https://checkout.na1.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl? ........" style="float: left; padding-top: 5px;" width="105"/>. Set it available without login